# What are the differences between throw error and return fail in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

When using `Sveltekit` and there are issues on endpoints and form action handlers (+page.server.ts and +server.ts) when should `throw error` and when should `return fail` be used? For `fail`:

```
return fail( status , {details} )
```

and when should an error be thrown instead?

```
throw error( status ,  message )
```

If the form action handler and endpoint are called from a use:enhancement form does that change which is more suitable to use? Will both be sent to the use:enhancement form handler or does error bypass it and go directly to error.svelte? In the docs I do not see how the fail is handled specifically in comparison to the thrown error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`error` is for serious issues that cause the `+error.svelte` to be displayed.

`fail` is for [form action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) results that are invalid, which can return relevant data to show, e.g. [validation errors](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#anatomy-of-an-action-validation-errors) for form fields.

> If the request couldn't be processed because of invalid data, you can return validation errors — along with the previously submitted form values — back to the user so that they can try again. The `fail` function lets you return an HTTP status code (typically 400 or 422, in the case of validation errors) along with the data. The status code is available through `$page.status` and the data through `form`

Comment: can you please expand on how the fail should be handled by the enhanced form submission function?

Comment: You usually don't, it sends data to the `form` property. The result should be of type `'failure'`, see [type docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-actionresult).